# Is there an event in ASP.NET for ColumnHeaderMouseClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, columnheader

I need help with a sorting problem I haven't been able to fix for the past 2 days and I think the only way I can fix it is with some type of event for clicking a column header to sort in my table.

Ultimately my problem is that I have auto generated fields and you can click on the column header to sort but I also have checkbox lists to filter what columns the user wants in the table. When that user filters out columns and then click one of the column headers, it clears all the column filters and the table selects all the columns while sorted by the column the user selected when the table was filtered.

I'm hoping with some event for clicking the mouse header that I can pretty much make that event be the same (besides sorting) as the search button event once you filter what columns you want.

Comment: Have you posted this (or a variation on this) before (recently)?  If this is classic ASP.NET web forms, then you need to maintain some state (in session) as to what's going on and manage it all by hand (if I remember correctly - it's been a long while).  You keep track of what the current sort and filter status is, and then apply them to your DataView (I'm assuming your are using a DataTable and a DataView) each time the user changes something.